# Uniform convergence of $tanh(nx)$

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis

Let $n\in \mathbb{N}$.

Please check if my reasoning is right:

$\tanh (nx)=\frac{1-\exp(-2nx)}{1+\exp(2nx)}$

$\exp(x)$ ist uniform convergent on $\mathbb{R}$. Therefore $\tanh (nx)$ is uniform convergent on $\mathbb{R}$

Is this right? If not where is it uniform convergent and for what $x$?

Comment: Uniformly convergent are sequences (or series) of functions (by definition). $\exp(x)$ is not such, so it doesn t make sense what you mean by "$\exp(x)$ is uniformly convergent".

Comment: Try some values, like $x=0, x = 1, x=-1$